# What units are available, world units, screen units?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand different types of units in unity. When I create a canvas (UI) then I believe these are set to world units meaning (I think) - 1 unit = 1 pixel?

I know by default my scene unit is 1 unit = 1 meter, what are these units called?

I suppose I am getting confused with all the different types of units around.

I know there are screen units, but how does this differ from world units ?

Does anyone know where I can find a good explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Units in unity world space are arbitrary, and it's subject to your interpretation.

In screen space however, it's obviously relative to the height and width of the screen, so it'd be apt to use a 1 unit to 1 pixel comparison.

It should be noted that, if you're importing sprites, there should be an import option to change the "pixel to unit" scale. For instance, by default (if i recall correctly), sprites have a 100 pixel to 1 unit scale.